# How can client know MSMQ MaximumQueueSize Quota has reached?

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I have noticed even after message queue quota has reached, "Send" method is not giving any signal to the client.

_messagequeue.MaximumQueueSize = 5;
_messagequeue.Send(message);

In the above example i'm expecting _messagequeue.Send(message); to throw "Insufficient Resource Exception" or some other signal once the queue quota is reached. however "Send" method will execute without any errors but messages will not enter the queue.. so how will client come to know when to stop pushing messages?

Answer (score 1):

As I remember you need to use transactions in MSMQ to be sure that message reached destination.

Answer (score 1):

see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754101(v=ws.10).aspx:
...you can request a NACK (negative acknowledgment) from the computer to which you are sending messages. If this acknowledgement is returned to your application, and indicates that the quota for this queue or machine has been reached, your application can either cease sending messages or offload the messages to another destination...

and further information about using that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx#bdadotnetasync2_topic4

Comment: Hi Ingo thanks a lot for your help.. and i checked all the AcknowledgeType's but none of them seem to help me here..
my requirement is very simple when queue reaches certain limit i want to stop my feeders? any sample would be greatly appreciated..